# Why do I get a 404 when trying to access /wp-admin/options-permalink.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I've been searching all over to understand what's going on, and I've come to understand that the issue is in the server's configuration. (No such issue with my local installs)

I've installed APC recently, and had flirted with trying to set up memecached, but I'm not understanding how this would have affected wp's ability to write to the .htaccess file!

Does anyone have some insight?

Comment: I've been able to stop the 404 from happening by commenting out lines 77-81, and the flush_rewrite_rules(); on :143.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was showing in the error logs, which made it hard to track the issue down, but I found that `apache_mod_loaded()` is hooked into `got_url_rewrite()` which gets called on `wp-admin/options-permalink.php:79`.

`apache_mod_loaded()` parses `phpinfo()` depending on your server config, and my PHP was throwing errors when `phpinfo()` was run. Likely a security measure.

I made a fresh build of PHP & Apache to fix this.

If you're desperate, frustrated, or don't mind hacking core, (and are at least aware that your server *is* capable of wp's requirements for url rewriting) just make `got_url_rewrite()` return `true`. `flush_rewrite_rules()` still ran as expected during my testing.